# Blazor app doesn't refresh UI after `StateHasChanged` in async operation

Tags: c#, async-await, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm struggling to understand how to implement asynchronous operations in my blazor app.

I have a class holding a collection of instances of a data class. The app allows adding and removing to/from that collection, process the updated collection (which is an expensive/long operation), and display the results.

I have code that works as expected for doing these operations synchronously. However, since the processing stage is long, it hangs the UI for some time, and I'd like to adapt my code to run asynchronously.

Here is a minimal reprducible example of my code:

Foo.cs:

```
namespace Example.Model
{
    public class Foo
    {
        public string Data { get; set; }
        public Foo() { Data = "bar"; }
    }
    public class FooCollection
    {
        public int Count => foos.Count;
        public string? Result { get; private set; }
        private List<Foo> foos;
        public FooCollection() 
        { 
            foos = new List<Foo>() { new Foo() };
            Result = foos.Single().Data;
        }
        public IList<Foo> GetFoos() { return foos; }
        public void CreateFooAt(int index)
        {
            foos.Insert(index, new Foo());
            UpdateResult();
        }
        public void RemoveFooAt(int index)
        {
            foos.RemoveAt(index);
            UpdateResult();
        }
        public async Task CreateFooAtAsync(int index)
        {
            foos.Insert(index, new Foo());
            await new Task(() => UpdateResult());
        }
        public async Task RemoveFooAtAsync(int index)
        {
            foos.RemoveAt(index);
            await new Task(() => UpdateResult());
        }
        private void UpdateResult()
        {
            Result = null;
            Thread.Sleep(1000); // Do some expensive operation on the data
            Result = foos.Select(f => f.Data).Aggregate((a, b) => a + ", " + b);
        }
    }
}
```

FooComponent.razor:

```
@using Example.Model

@for (int i = 0; i < foos.Count; i++)
{
    int iCopy = i;
    var foo = foos.GetFoos()[i];
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-3">
            <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="@(() => InsertFooAt(iCopy))">Insert above</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="@(() => RemoveFooAt(iCopy))">Delete</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="@(() => InsertFooAt(iCopy+1))">InsertBelow</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3">
            <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="@(() => InsertFooAtAsync(iCopy))">Insert above async</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="@(( ) => RemoveFooAtAsync(iCopy))">Delete async</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="@(() => InsertFooAtAsync(iCopy+1))">InsertBelow async</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" @bind-value="@foo.Data"/>
        </div>
    </div>
}

@if (foos.Result == null)
{
    <div class="spinner-border" role="status">
        <span class="visually-hidden">Loading...</span>
    </div>
}
else
{
    <span class="border-success">@foos.Result</span>
}

@code {
    FooCollection foos = new FooCollection();

    void InsertFooAt(int index)
    {
        foos.CreateFooAt(index);
    }
    void RemoveFooAt(int index)
    {
        foos.RemoveFooAt(index);
    }

    async Task InsertFooAtAsync(int index)
    {
        await foos.CreateFooAtAsync(index);
        StateHasChanged();
    }
    async Task RemoveFooAtAsync(int index)
    {
        await foos.RemoveFooAtAsync(index);
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

As stated, the synchronous methods for adding and removing rows work as expected, but hang the UI for a second.

However, the asynchronous methods do not trigger a UI refresh upon completion, leading to different states shown in the display of the collection and of the results. I also tried signaling the state change with `await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged)`, with no difference with the code above. How could I fix that?

Moreover, there is no path in the current code allowing to update the UI and spinner after `Result` is invalidated and before completion, to communicate the operation's status with the user. Where could I hook this feature in the code?

Comment: Is the Processing stage expensive in processor time or has significant latency?    And are you on WASM or Server?

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis Expensive mostly in processor time, plus some latency due to client-server communication. I'm on Blazor Server

Comment: See my answer, which hopefully clarifies what you are doing wrong and answers your questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `CreateFooAtAsync` this code `await new Task(() => UpdateResult())` starts a Task that never completes.  So consequently `CreateFooAtAsync` never completes: it's resource leaky code.

The page below simplifies and refactors your code into a Minimal Reproducible Example to both illustrate your problem and show how to resolve it.

If your code is processor intensive, and you are running on Server, then you [may] need to run it on a different thread.  If it's mainly latency issues you are trying to deal with, then using async `await` will keep the UI responsive.

`await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged)` doesn't miraculously make the render async: it just ensures the `StateHasChanged` method is run on the [renderer] Synchronisation Context.

If you look at my code below, there's no need to call `StateHasChanged`.  The logic works and the `ComponentBase` built in UI handler calls it for you.

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<div>
    <button class="btn btn-danger" @onclick="DoLeakyAsync" >Update</button>
    <button class="btn btn-dark" @onclick="DoAsync">Update</button>
    <button class="btn btn-success" @onclick="DoHighLatencyAsync">Update</button>
</div>

<div class="bg-dark text-white m-2 p-2">
<pre>@_message</pre>
</div>
@code {
    private string? _message;

    public async Task DoLeakyAsync()
    {
        _message = null;
        // this is a memory/resource leak - it creates a task that never completes
        await new Task(() => UpdateExpensiveResult());
        // Add a break point here and see if you reach it
    }

    public async Task DoAsync()
    {
        _message = null;
        // Offloads the task to a threadpool thread.
        // Can only do in Server - WASM has only one thread
        await Task.Run(UpdateExpensiveResult);
    }

    public async Task DoHighLatencyAsync()
    {
        _message = null;
        await UpdateHighLatencyResult();
    }

    private void UpdateExpensiveResult()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000); // Do some expensive operation on the data
        _message = $"processed at {DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()}";
    }

    private async Task UpdateHighLatencyResult()
    {
        // emulate a slow API or data get call
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        _message = $"processed at {DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()}";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you created `Foo.cs` simply to test however the majority of the problem lies there.

1. `new Task()`

```
await new Task(() => UpdateResult());
```

`new Task()` creates the task but does not actually start it.

What you want to use instead is `Task.Run`, this creates and starts the task.

2. `Thread.Sleep`

You could wrap this with a `Task.Run()` however the delay is still happening synchronously so the UI will have no knowledge of when that blocking is done. So this is bound to cause unexpected behaviours.

I would recommend creating an asynchronous variation of the UpdateMethod, and use the async `Task.Delay()` instead.

```
private async Task UpdateResultAsync()
{
    Result = null;
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    Result = foos.Select(f => f.Data).Aggregate((a, b) => a + ", " + b);
}
```

Lastly i'd recommend using the async variation of `StateHasChanged()` which is `await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);`.

Here's a [fiddle with the changes](https://blazorfiddle.com/s/z5gfbbps)

Edit: Calling `StateHasChanged` is not required, refer to [Mr C's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76978501/11779494)

Comment: There won't be any issue with `Thread.Sleep` in the real thing as this is a mere placeholder for an expensive operation. Thanks for the insight, though.